# PyCharm deletes quotation marks in paramenter field

Tags: python, parameters, pycharm, escaping, quotation-marks

I want to set a parameter for a python script by using the parameter field in PyCharm.

My config:

[image: run configuration]

But the command in the Run console is:

`python3 path_to_script.py '{app_id: picoballoon_network, dev_id: ferdinand_8c ... and so on`

and not:

`python3 path_to_script.py '{"app_id": "picoballoon_network", "dev_id": "ferdinand_8c" ... and so on`

Basically, it deletes all `"` in the parameter.
Does anyone know how to turn this off?

My PyCharm version is:

```
PyCharm 2020.3.1 (Professional Edition)
Build #PY-203.6682.86, built on January 4, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.9.1+11-b1145.37 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Windows 10 10.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the quotation marks being deleted notice the rules to writing parameters that contain quotation marks.

> **Run/Debug Configuration: Python**
>
> [**Configuration tab**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python.html#1)
>
> When specifying the script parameters, follow these rules:
>
> - Use spaces to separate individual script parameters.
> - Script parameters containing spaces should be delimited with double quotes, for example, `some" "param` or `"some param"`.
> - If script parameter includes double quotes, escape the double quotes with backslashes, for example:
>
> ```
> -s"main.snap_source_dirs=[\"pcomponents/src/main/python\"]" -s"http.cc_port=8189"
> -s"backdoor.port=9189"
> -s"main.metadata={\"location\": \"B\", \"language\": \"python\", \"platform\": \"unix\"}"
> ```

The case in the question would be a single parameter, lets apply the rules to the example:

`'{"app_id": "picoballoon_network", "dev_id": "ferdinand_8c"'`

1. Because it's a single parameter containing spaces it has to be surounded by quotation marks.
2. Since the content of the parameter also contains quotation marks they must be escaped using a backslash `\`. So applying the parameter formatting rules gives:

`"'{\"app_id\": \"picoballoon_network\", \"dev_id\": \"ferdinand_8c\"}'"`

3. **(Side note):** In the example the parameter was surrounded by [Apostrophes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostrophe), this may be unnecessary and will probably have to be stripped later in your Python code (the below example uses the [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=strip#str.strip) method).

You can test it with this simple script:

```py
import sys
import ast


your_dictionary = ast.literal_eval(sys.argv[1].strip("'"))
```

**(Side note)**: Your example parameter is a string containing a [Python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), there are several ways to convert it, in the example I included the highest voted answer from this question: [*"Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/988228/10794031)

A screenshot showing the parameter and test code in use:

[image]