# Passing a JSON as a parameter from the run configuration in PyCharm

Tags: python, json, parameters, pycharm, escaping

Can someone please tell me how to pass a JSON as a script parameter from the parameters field of the run configuration?

I'm trying to pass this JSON:

`{"beam":5,"max_len_a":1.2,"max_len_b":10}`

tried:

`'{"beam":5,"max_len_a":1.2,"max_len_b":10}'`
`"{"beam":5,"max_len_a":1.2,"max_len_b":10}"`
`\"{"beam":5,"max_len_a":1.2,"max_len_b":10}\"`
`"{\"beam\":5,\"max_len_a\":1.2,\"max_len_b\":10}"`

All failed.

Comment: Hello, did you see the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Passing the example parameter in the question is relatively straightforward. The only rule applying is that the quotes (`"`) have to be escaped using backslashes (`\"`). For a more complicated example with more rules applying see [Pycharm deletes quotation marks in paramenter field](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65568789).

> **Run/Debug Configuration: Python**
>
> [**Configuration tab**](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-python.html#1)
>
> When specifying the script parameters, follow these rules:
>
> (...)
>
> - If script parameter includes double quotes, escape the double quotes with backslashes,

So the example JSON string:

`{"beam":5,"max_len_a":1.2,"max_len_b":10}`

should be written as:

`{\"beam\":5,\"max_len_a\":1.2,\"max_len_b\":10}`

You can then easily convert the parameter to a JSON object using the script

```py
import json
import sys

your_string = sys.argv[1]
z = json.loads(your_string)
```

The following screenshot shows the run configurations:

[image]